# Flutter build failed due to use of deprecated Android v1 embedding

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an error in the flutter project that I cloned from GitHub. I tried this method but it didn't work

```
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
```

To:

```
<application
        android:name="${applicationName}"
```

**error:**

[image]

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

[image]

Comment: try to clean and build again. flutter clean. flutter pub get . and run again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution I found when I got this problem with my older Flutter projects is to start fresh.

1. Rename the old project folder.
2. Create a new Flutter project using the latest Android Studio or command line.
3. Copy/paste the old code from your backup folder.
4. Be careful not to replace any of the control files: pubspec.yaml, Android folder, iOS folder, Gradle, etc.
5. You will find the problem solved.

Answer (score 8):

It may sound like a fake solution, but indeed, the easiest way to resolve this is:

1. Delete the `android` folder.
2. Run `flutter create .`

The command will recreate the `android` folder with the already migrated code. Also, the command will create folders for the other stable platforms (e.g. web, windows), so you could ignore those and just delete them or trigger the `flutter create` command by defining android platform - `flutter create --platforms=android .`.

Comment: It is applicable for small projects. What if i have some custom staff in android folder? And this was written not by me?

Comment: I see, but as long as you are using GIT or just make a backup of the directory before deleting it, you must be fine.

Comment: @mkobuolys didn't work for me. I deleted `android` folder as you said, and when I run `flutter create` it throws an error:  No option specified for the output directory.
Create a new Flutter project.

Comment: Did you run `flutter create` or `flutter create .`? As the error says, you probably haven't defined the output directory.

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice the `.` i ran flutter create without the dot.

Answer (score 2):

Add below lines in `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<meta-data
    android:name="flutterEmbedding"
    android:value="2" />
```

For more details : https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/android-v1-embedding-create-deprecation

Answer (score 2):

Add the following code in android manifest after activity

```
<meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
```

[image]

In project build.gradle add the following code in buildscript

```
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
```

[image]

And change gradle version in gradle-wrapper.properties

[image]

My manifest file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.stackoverflowexample">
   <application
        android:label="stackoverflowexample"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

in AndroidManifest.xml
inside <application ... just replace android to:
`android:name="${applicationName}"`