# When I run a Flutter project, it says "build failed due to use of deprecated android v1 embedding"

Tags: flutter

It says:

> build failed due to use of deprecated android v1 embedding.

Image:

[image]

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71492645/flutter-build-failed-due-to-use-of-deprecated-android-v1-embedding/71492791#71492791

Comment: Please do not post images of code or errors. Instead, please [edit] your question and paste the code and errors in directly. Images can't be copied and pasted into an editor and compiled to reproduce the problem, are hard to read on mobile devices, may be blocked by proxies or firewalls, and can't be searched and therefore aren't useful to future readers.  For more information, please see [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/).