# Please guide me, how to fix this issue?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

Warning:
Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android
embedding. It is being deprecated in favor of Android embedding v2. Follow the
steps at

https://flutter.dev/go/android-project-migration

to migrate your project. You may also pass the --ignore-deprecation flag to
ignore this check and continue with the deprecated v1 embedding. However,
the v1 Android embedding will be removed in future versions of Flutter.

The detected reason was:

C:\Users\M ZEESHAN\Downloads\Quizzy-App-master\Quizzy-App-master\android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml uses `android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"`

Build failed due to use of deprecated Android v1 embedding.

Comment: check my answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71492645/flutter-build-failed-due-to-use-of-deprecated-android-v1-embedding/71492791#71492791

Comment: Hav you tried to follw the steps mentioned in the link suggested by the error message? Please try that

Answer (score 0):

Remove android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
from Manifest.xml

Then change

> public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
>
> @Override
>
> public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine flutterEngine) {
> GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
>
> }
> }

to

> public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
>
> }

Although since the project is old i guess you have to change the distributionUrl to distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7.1-all.zip

in gradle-wrapper.properites